# SSH into Ubuntu MAAS

Tags: networking, ssh, maas

I'm testing out MAAS. I've PXE booted a VM in vCenter to install ubuntu 18.04. The machine booted up and got an IP address.

Problem is, I can't seem to SSH into it. I've made sure to import the SSH key by doing:

```
john john-lnx ~ $ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
# Copy the output, and paste it in the MAAS webgui for SSH keys. (I've done that in the MAAS installation but again now for troubleshooting)
```

When I try to SSH into the machine, this is what I get:

```
john john-lnx ~ $ ssh ubuntu@172.24.25.232 -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/john/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/john/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.24.25.232 [172.24.25.232] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 172.24.25.232:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 172.24.25.232 port 22
```

Is this caused by the `key_load_public` it seems to look for? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please check permissions of the file `/home/john/.ssh/id_rsa` as the connection is established but the file is not found. In my last case it was a permission mistake.

The `.ssh` directory permissions should be 700 (`drwx------`).  The public key (`.pub` file) should be 644 (`-rw-r--r--`). The private key (id_rsa) on the client host, and the `authorized_keys` file on the server, should be 600 (`-rw-------`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. `id_rsa.pub` is 644 and `id_rsa` is 600. Problem is, I have no control to the remote server at all. MAAS only allows logging in with SSH keys, which are not working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Entries in `/var/log/auth.log` will show more info. Notices like `Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` and `No supported key exchange algorithms [preauth]` indicate a problem with the keys files.

A drop after `SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT` is likely also related to the keys.

So please do a `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` and check the connection again.

Leave a comment if this does not work and Ill delete this :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, do it on my local machine or the remote server? I'm asking because I don't have access to the remote server.